# Time is not convering nanoseconds to seconds right

Tags: java, performance

can someone catch if there is anythong wrong with my code. I am trying to time how long it is taking to do this factorial and convert it to seconds, but it seems to be printing out a wrong value. Thanks!!

```
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    BigInteger factorial_minute = doFactorial(50000);
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();

    String factorial_minute_str = factorial_minute.toString();
    System.out.println("Largest n! in one minute = " + factorial_minute);
    System.out.println("n! in one minute Amount of Digits: " + factorial_minute_str.length()); // Print the length also
    System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (int)((endTime - startTime)/1000000000 + " seconds") );
```

The output is

> Total execution time: 4 seconds

EDIT, I changed it to be 1000000000, but it seems like the output is still wrong.

Comment: As written above, it should not even compile.  You have a misplaced `)` after `" seconds"`, it should come after `1000000000`, otherwise you are trying to cast a `long` + `String` to `int`.

Comment: Oh yeah, that was a quick typo i did when editing this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One nanosecond is one billionth of a second, not one millionth. Add three more zeros to your divisor.

```
(endTime - startTime)/1000000000
```

Comment: I changed it to this, but it seems look like the execution time is wrong, is it outputting wrong?

Comment: @AustinTruong It shouldn't be wrong, I guess your feeling is not so precise. Use currentTimeMillis() to check again?